# Blocking a large URL list

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have a problem with my Chrome extension.

I made a Chrome extension which just blocks urls listed inside the `background.js`.

The problem comes from the `background.js` which has more than 2 million urls inside, so when I install my extension on Chrome, the browser becomes really really slow.

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) { 
    return {cancel: true};
  }, { urls: [ /* 2+ million URL patterns */ ] }, ["blocking"]
);
```

I know it has to be a solution maybe in another way, maybe I have to store those URLs locally instead inside the `background.js`?

Comment: Show us how it's currently done. And please take time to edit your post to improve readability.

Comment: THIS is my background.js:

chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
function(details) { return {cancel: true}; 
}, { urls: 
[
"*://*.urls/*",
] }, ["blocking"]); 

at the "*://*.urls/*", i have my 2 millions urls

Comment: I've cleaned up your question. Please take time to read through the [Site Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) guides to learn more about how to make a good SO question.

Comment: thanks for your help :D i would like to know if this: { urls: [ /* 2+ million URL patterns */ ] }   is the solution to my problem?

Comment: No, it's just a description of the problem.

Comment: Have you tried the [`chrome.declarativeWebRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/declarativeWebRequest) API?

Comment: nope i have read the article but i don't know how to use that in my manifest.json and the background.js

Comment: @RobW This API is not yet stable, and the OP indicated that he needs this urgently (I edited it out of the question as fluff)

Comment: @Xan The API is stable as in usable, but there is no active owner at Chromium to maintain the API, hence it is is not available in Chromium stable.

Comment: im trying to fins a soluton but don't know how to solve that :s

Comment: Important question, how do your URLs look like? Do you only block by host name?

Comment: simples urls sometimes with http://url.com and with www.url.com, etc

Comment: how to solve my problem???

Comment: I asked you to read some site guides, and you didn't (there's a simple way to check). Please learn to use Stack Overflow properly.